# How often does loadHTMLFile get called in a single PHP-script?

Tags: php, domdocument

Since my english is bad, the title questions might be a bit irritating, but I will get specific:

At the beginning of my PHP-script I call a HTML-file to get content out of it with the help of XPath.

```
$url = "http://www....";

$html = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
```

The target website I'm getting content from has a lot of information I need, but I have to do several different XPath-queries (30 to be exactly).

```
$xpath_match = $xpath->query('...');
```

My first thought was everytime I use a XPath-query by `loadHTMLFile` it calls the target website individually - again and again. This would cause a lot of (unnecessary) traffic and would slow down my script heavily.

I googled a bit, read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php), but both seem to suggest that once I called the target website at the beginning of my script it is stored as long as the script runs, and every XPath-query just reads the stored content.

However, yesterday I got an error concerning `loadHTMLFile`, saying I called it too often in the last hour. Still, I only refreshed my website with the PHP-script around 10 times in that specific hour. That's not really often and I am targeting something like around 150 to 200 website calls per hour in the future.

Someone out there that can clarifiy the issue? And if the content is stored, what was the reason for the error? And is there a workaround then?

Comment: This loads the URL only once (unless you _call_ `loadHTMLFile` multiple times in different locations.) _“what was the reason for the error?”_ - could simply be the “target site” becoming aware of what you are trying to do, and blocking it … have you _asked_ whether you are allowed to use their content? _“And is there a workaround then?”_ - using a proper API, where available. And if not, checking with the owner of the target site first, whether they are ok with this, and based on what they might apply restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Load the HTML once, using `file_get_contents()` :

```
$code = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$html = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html->loadHTML($code);
```